# KeyListener not being called

Tags: java, swing

I have a `GUI` class that extends JFrame, and a separate inner class `KeyPresses` that extends `KeyAdapter`.  In my constructor for `GUI`, I pass in an instance of `KeyAdapter` to `addKeyListener()`.  As far as I can tell, this is all I need to do, but for some reason, it is not being called when I press a key.

Applicable code:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
  public GUIMaze(Options options){
    addKeyListener(new KeyPresses());
    ...more code...
  }
  private class KeyPresses extends KeyAdapter{
     @Override
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        ...code that is not being run...
     }
  }
}
```

The odd thing is that this code *used* to work, before I did some refactoring.  Either I removed something that I needed, or I am doing something else that is conflicting with `KeyPresses`.

I only have 1 `KeyListener`, and my `MouseListener` works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue with `KeyListener`.  A `KeyListener` will only raise events when the component it is attached to is focusable AND has keyboard focus.

Instead, it is recommended that you use the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API, which provides you with the control to determine at what focus level the binding should be triggered.

Comment: So, if I understand you right, my JFrame doesn't have the focus for some reason, and KeyListeners only listen if JFrame receives the keystroke.  A Key Binding will respond if the JFrame, or any of its children receive a keystroke?

Comment: It's not that your frame doesn't have focus, it's that component you have registered your `KeyListener` doesn't or can't (most base components aren't focusable by default).  But, yes.  If you configure the key bindings correctly, then it won't matter

Comment: JFrame doesn't have a getInputMap() function...so how am I supposed to use Key Bindings on it?

Comment: Normally, I create a `JPanel` and set it as the frames `contentPane`

Comment: `JFrame doesn't have a getInputMap() function...` - you can use the JRootPane of the frame.

Comment: @camickr, I saw a seperate SO question do that, and have already implemented it...works like a charm.  Thanks though!